# In SharePoint workflow to Reject Task ; I need to make the comment field required

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

In SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow on Rejected request; I need to make the comment field required. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new editform and add JavaScript to the form.

In your code, check the value of result task. Use the `PreSaveAction()` to return true if it's approved, and make a condition for the reject status.

Example:
`editformXXXX.aspx`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreSaveAction() {  
        var value = $("select[title='task result'] option:selected").text();
        var value2 = $("textarea[title='Body']").val();

        if (value=="Approuvée") { 
            return true; 
        }
        else {
            if(value2 != "") {
               return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('Please give a comment');
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    } 

</script>
```